# IBM Domino Designer Creating a sample application

Tags: lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm new to IBM Domino Designer. I'm trying to create an IBM Domino Designer application which has 2 fields and a button. Once click on the button the data has to be stored in DB.

Now the problem is how to store the data in DB and where to write this code?

Should it be either in Button click or do we need to write any agent for it?

Answer (score 1):

Create an application via "File" - "Application" "New"

Click "Create" - "Design" - "Form" in a designer client.

Name the Form, "Test" for example.

Insert a field in the form via "Create" - "Field" , name that field, for example "field1".

Insert some button via create - hotspot - button.

Paste this code in the action section:

```
@If(@Command([FileSave]);@Command([FileCloseWindow]);@Prompt([Ok];"Attention!";"Error saving document"))
```

Save the form

Go to the Notes Client, Open your Application, click Create menu, choose the form name, "Test" in our example and you will get a new document created by form "Test".

You should see a white form with a brackets in it and a button.
You can type some text inside brackets and can push the button. Formula action will try to save and close the document When you press the button.

Thats it. You have got an application with the form where you can put some data into the field and save it to DB.

Answer (score 0):

Designing Lotus Notes Databases is nothing, that you can learn from scratch without having any clue or a good teacher. 
You could start with the help and click through starting at "IBM Domino Designer Basic User Guide and Reference > Application Design", but I doubt that you will ever be successful.

As long as you do not understand, what Lotus Notes Databases are all about, you will not be able to create even the most simple application.

To give you at least a starting point: Lotus Notes Databases are simple "unstructured" containers for everything you throw in there. Data is presented as "Notes Document" and can contain Structured Data, Images, Attachments, Tables, whatever...

To create a document the easiest way is to create a "Form" in Lotus Notes Designer, create some fields in that form and then use the "Preview in Notes"- Button to show the Form in Lotus Notes. Using Ctrl + S you can save the document, that you created with the form.

Then you use "Views" to show the "documents" that you created.

Now I explained 2 Design- Elements out of 20 "Base"- Design elements, and you might already got lost...

Take my advice: Let someone teach you, how to do this, there is no other sensible way to learn developing applications in Lotus Notes (now Known as IBM Notes)